# getUser() returning 0 when using php SDK. It was working a few days ago and the code has not changed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the php SDK getUser() function to receive a facebook user's ID, but now it's returning 0 when a few days ago it was returning the correct ID. Has something changed? Any reason why it would stop working all of a sudden?

Comment: Has your access token expired? You will want to get a token that doesnt expire

Comment: I just want to get the user id, if the user is logged in to facebook. You shouldn't need an access token for that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need an access token for getting the user id. Just authorize your user (again) with "getLoginUrl": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Be aware that a user access token is valid for 2 hours only (or 60 days if you extend it with "setExtendedAccessToken").

If it doesn´t work even after authorizing the user with getLoginUrl, keep in mind that you have to call that url again to refresh the access token. Also, make sure your PHP SDK is up to date and the settings are correct (App-ID and App-Secret).

Comment: The user is coming from a "getLoginUrl" to make sure that a user is logged in but it is still returning 0 so I don't think that's the problem.

With that said, I don't think you need an access token to get a user id if that user is logged in to facebook. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk , in the first example, there is no parameter for an access token being passed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/ , in this part of the documentation, there is no mention of using an access token to get the facebook user id either.

Comment: i know for a fact that you definitely need a (user) access token to get the user id. even if he is logged in to facebook, the important thing is that he needs to authorize your app. but you don´t need to worry about the access token, that will happen in the background while using the php sdk. and that´s why it isn´t mentioned in the basic code.

Comment: it may help to include your login code in the question. i´ve added some more information in my answer, but without the code it´s harder to help.